# In 64bit R, what should my memory.limit() be set to?

Tags: r, memory, 64-bit

I intend to work with some large vectors in R.

`memory.limit` currently gives:

> memory.limit()
>
> [1] 4095

But I think that this is the default for *32bit* R, whilst my installation is *64bit*.

What should my `memory.limit()` be set to in 64bit R?

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your machine? 4 Gb? Note that for 32-bit version, the maximum is 3Gb.

Comment: 64bit Windows 7 with 4GB ram

Comment: So you reached the limits of your machine. `memory.limit()` returns the total amount of RAM you have.

Comment: I see - so `memory.limit` can only be set between 0 and the amount of ram you have?

Comment: Yes. It is designed to restrict memory usage on Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memory.limit` is used to limit memory usage. It can be set to any value between 0 and the amount of available ram on the machine.

The "correct" value for working with large data sets is the full amount of ram available. So, for example, with 4GB of ram, 4095 is the appropriate value: `memory.limit(4095)`.